# MIME types that allow XSS in modern browsers

Tags: web-browser, xss, javascript, mime-type

Assume that it is possible to host arbitrary files on `goodguys.com`, which are delivered with an attacker-controlled MIME type and `X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff`. Which MIME types allow for XSS when used as src of an iframe, target of a link or in other ways in reasonably modern browsers? I know of at least `text/html` and `image/svg+xml`, but are there others?

Edit: I want to stress that a blacklist approach based on MIME types is not a good idea. The motivation for the question is that I could use interesting answers as convincing arguments in favor of MIME whitelists.

Comment: off the top of my head: xhtml, hta, xml+xslt, swf, and pdf (sometimes).

Comment: That's an interesting question, but you won't get a comprehensive list covering all major browsers. If you're planning a real-life implementation, you should go with a whitelist of harmless content types instead of blacklisting dangerous ones.

Comment: @Arminius: Thanks for pointing this out, the approach described in my question is certainly not advisable. I have edited the question to clarify why I'm asking it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You won't be able to assemble a comprehensive list of dangerous MIME types.**

While it's straightforward to block `text/html`, `text/xml`, `image/svg+xml`, etc., there are many obscure legacy or vendor-specific MIME types that aren't widely known and might work in *some* browsers. E.g., the MIME type `application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml` is understood as XML in Firefox while it won't trigger in Chrome at all. Proof of concept:

```
data:application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml,<x:script xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">alert(1)</x:script>
```

Also, there are MIME types that don't immediately lead to XSS but have side effects. E.g., an attacker might want to trick a user into installing a Firefox plugin by supplying content with a `application/x-xpinstall` MIME type. (This attack will have some additional hurdles, but you get the idea.)

Finally, third-party vendors might also register their own custom MIME types (think Flash applets with `application/x-shockwave-flash`, JAVA applets, embedded media players, etc.) some of which have the ability to execute script code. It will be hard to keep track of these on your blacklist.

In conclusion - if you're planning a real-life implementation, you should whitelist harmless MIME types instead of blacklisting dangerous ones.